# How to create a mask for all relatively white parts of an image using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Say I have 2 white images (RGB 800x600 image) that is 'dirty' at some unknown positions, I want to create a final combined image that has all the dirty parts of both images.

Just adding the images together reduces the 'dirtyness' of each blob, since I half the pixel values and then add them (to stay in the 0->255 rgb range), this is amplified when you have more than 2 images.

What I want to do is create a mask for all relatively white pixels in the 3 channel image, I've seen that if all RGB values are within 10-15 of each other, a pixel is relatively white. How would I create this mask using numpy?

Pseudo code for what I want to do:

```
img = cv2.imread(img) #BGR image
mask = np.where( BGR within 10 of each other)
```

Then I can use the first image, and replace pixels on it where the second picture is not masked, keeping the 'dirtyness level' relatively dirty. (I know some dirtyness of the second image will replace that of the first, but that's okay)

Edit:
People asked for images so I created some sample images, the white would not always be so exactly white as in these samples which is why I need to use a 'within 10 BGR' range.

Image 1
[image: Image 1]

Image 2
[image: Image 2]

Image 3 (combined, ignore the difference in yellow blob from image 2 to here, they should be the same)
[image: Image 3]

Comment: Why not grayscaling your images, if you're just interested in white-ish colors?

Comment: Kindly share a representative image, and hopefully a *"cleaned up"* version too, so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I added some images for clarification

Comment: I don't really follow your description, but I think you want to copy the yellow coloured pixels from your second image onto your first (background) image. If that is correct, I would suggest you convert your second image to HSV with `cvtColor(...cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)` and find the pixels with higher Saturation, i.e. the coloured pixels, and copy them over the background image. That will still work if your *"splodge"* changes colour from yellow to blue or orange etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you asked for is having the pixels in which the distance between colors is under 10.

Here it is, translated to numpy.

```
img = cv2.imread(img) #  assuming rgb image in naming
r = img[:, :, 0]
g = img[:, :, 1]
b = img[:, :, 2]
rg_close = np.abs(r - g) < 10
gb_close = np.abs(g - b) < 10
br_close = np.abs(b - r) < 10

all_close = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(rg_close, gb_close), br_close)
```

I do believe, however, that this is not what you REALLY want.

I think what you want in a mask that segments the background.

This is actually simpler, assuming the background is completely white:

```
img = cv2.imread(img)
background_mask = 245 * 3 < img[: ,: ,0] + img[: ,: ,1] + img[: ,: ,2]
```

Please note this code required thresholding games, and only shows a concept.

Comment: The white isnt always as white as in the example images. Imagine a shadow over the color white, you can still see with your eyes it's white, and the rgb pixel values are still within in, but not close to 245*3 or even 200*3 sometimes. Its probably worth a shot, just dont have the time to try it :/

Comment: @Joram In that case, you could try a simple edge detector, and mask with that. I would expect an edge pixel not to be background. the simplest edge detection would be (for a grayscale image): `vertical = img[1:, :] - img[:1, :]` `horizontal = img[:, 1:] - img[:, :1]` and `edges = vertical + horizontal` `outline=edges>threshold`. play with the offset (+-1, didn't figure it out) and you would get a pretty clear outline. then you can use a filling algorithm with a seed according to color.
just another idea...

Comment: You could also try canny to find edges and then create a mask by filling with a seed growing from the whitest pixel

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you convert to [HSV colourspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and look for saturated (colourful) pixels like this:

```
import cv2

# Load background and foreground images
bg = cv2.imread('A.jpg')
fg = cv2.imread('B.jpg')

# Convert to HSV colourspace and extract just the Saturation
Sat = cv2.cvtColor(fg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[..., 1]

# Find best (Otsu) threshold to divide black from white, and apply it
_ , mask = cv2.threshold(Sat,0,1,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# At each pixel, choose foreground where mask is set and background elsewhere
res = np.where(mask[...,np.newaxis], fg, bg)

# Save the result
cv2.imwrite('result.png', res)
```

[image]

Note that you can modify this if it picks up too many or too few coloured pixels. If it picks up too few, you could dilate the mask and if it it picks up too many, you could erode the mask. You could also blur the image a little bit before masking which might not be a bad idea as it is a *"nasty"* JPEG with compression artefacts in it. You could change the saturation test and make it more clinical and targeted if you only wanted to allow certain colours through, or a certain brightness or a comnbination.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is also a pretty good solution indeed. I should definitely get more comfortable with HSV