# Different ways to detect LED Screen from the image

Tags: python, opencv

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLlAs.jpg)

I want to extract the LED screen from the image above. Some approaches that I have tried include:

1. I first converted the image to HSV and made a trackbar GUI through which I noted at what value of HSV our mask filters out our ROI.
2. using canny edge detection, contours extraction, and selecting the contour with 4 vertices and area greater than 100

Both of the solutions do work.

The problem with the first approach is that it only works on a pinkish screen. While the second approach is more generic, but both approaches need a lot of fine-tuning to get the required result.

My question is that if there's any other more generalised approach that I can try.

Comment: use a simple cnn to train to detect and then capture the image.

Comment: I have to solve this using OpenCV

Comment: How much variation do you expect in the image? Is it always this machine? Always this colour? Always this size in the frame? Always full-face or sometimes at an oblique angle?

Comment: Always this machine and same angle. everthing else is expected to change

Comment: Have you considered multi-scale template matching to look for the `A` and `B` or up/down buttons? If you then measured the distance between them you could calculate where the screen is.

Comment: Ok, Let me try that. I'll keep you updated

Comment: @Mark I tried that. it worked really well. Thanks. Do you any other approach in mind that I can try?

Comment: I'm guessing other machines you are photographing are maybe equally gaudy colours? If so, you could convert to HSV/HSL colourspace, take the Saturation channel, look for saturated colours and threshold them which would give you white where the green machine is and black elsewhere - specifically where the LED screen is. Then you could run a *"Connected Components Analysis"* to look for the black screen, or flood-fill the outer edges of the image with black and hope you were left with just the machine in white and the screen in black in the middle. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63939203/2836621